# How to add authorisation logic to the base topic in a Phoenix Channel so that all subtopics gets the same logic

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

My user_socket have

```
defmodule MyappServerWeb.UserSocket do
  use Phoenix.Socket

  ## Channels
  channel "public:login", MyappServerWeb.LoginChannel

  channel "admin:navbar", MyappServerWeb.AdminNavbarChannel
  channel "admin:dash", MyappServerWeb.AdminDashChannel
  channel "admin:user", MyappServerWeb.UserChannel
end
```

Here i have to implement two authorization level, ie, **public** and **admin**. All subtopics under these two topic must inherit the same authorization logic i set to the parent topic. How to achieve this? or Am i doing anything wrong? (really new to functional programming)

Comment: Create a separate module with the shared logic and call that from within each channels `join/3` function?

Comment: but i have to call it in each and every join/3 functions... if i could apply that logic to basetopic and if all subtopic gets inherited, that would be nice :)

Comment: Then create a `MyApp.AdminSocket` and put your logic in the `connect/2` function. Then only tell it about the admin channels and keep your `MyApp.UserSocket` to only know about the public channels.

Comment: Same client needs to access both public: and admin: topics... if i did, like what u say.. it wont be possible right? since one client can only connect to one connect/2

Comment: i need single socket connections with different authorization levels for different base topic and need to know, is there any way to make it inherit to all the subtopics..

Comment: In your endpoint.ex file you can define multiple sockets. There is no reason you cannot connect to multiple sockets. Or go with what I said originally and put the common logic into a separate module and write 1 line of code in your join functions.

Comment: I will go with separate socket endpoints and having separate connect/2 function. if u can add this as an answer (like no possible way of  implementing this) i will be happy to accept it as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The common approach to share the logic between different modules would be to use `__using__/1` callback from calls to [`Kernel.use/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#use/2).

```
defmodule SharedLogic do
  defmacro __using__(opts \\ []) do
    quote do
      defdelegate login(user), to: SharedLogic
      def logged?(user), do: SOME CODE
    end
  end

  def login(user) do
    SOME LOGIC
  end
end
```

And now in your implementations you just do:

```
defmodule Admin do
  use SharedLogic
end
```

The above will add `login/1` and `logged/1` functions to `Admin` module. Your code already uses this technique for `Phoenix.Socket`, you might examine [it’s code for the inspiration](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/v1.3.0/lib/phoenix/socket.ex#L159).

I effectively omitted the `@behaviour`-related stuff, that is usually added to `SharedLogic` to type-check the modules using `SharedLogic`, for the sake of simplicity.

More info on [`Kernel.defdelegate/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#defdelegate/2).

Answer (score -1):

Usually it can be done using macros to share the same logic among different parts of code. You can make a module in which you write your logic and then in the `web.ex` file like this

```
    def channel do
      quote do
       use Project.module name
      end
   end
```

After that you can use this any where like this `use project.web, :module name`.